# Android Country code from Contry name using spinner

Tags: android, spinner, country-codes

In my android aplication a mobile number verification part is there for that I gt string array for all cuntries and we can select all countries name from spinner .. and I also have the cuntry codes .. What I need is when user select a cuntry name from spinner .. its particular ISD cde has t display in the edittext ... what I need t do for that

I am giving what I did

```
<string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Afghanistan</item>
        <item>Aland Islands</item>
<item>Albania</item>
<item>Algeria</item>
<item>American Samoa</item>
<item>Andorra</item>
<item>Angola</item>
<item>Anguilla</item>
<item>Antarctica</item>
<item>Antigua and Barbuda</item>
<item>Argentina</item>
<item>Armenia</item>
<item>Aruba</item>
<item>Australia</item>
<item>Austria</item>
<item>Azerbaijan</item>
<item>Bahrain</item>
<item>Bangladesh</item>
<item>Barbados</item>
<item>Belarus</item>
<item>Belgium</item>
<item>Belize</item>
<item>Benin</item>
<item>Bermuda</item>
<item>Bhutan</item>
<item>Bolivia</item>
<item>Bosnia and Herzegovina</item>
<item>Botswana</item>
<item>Bouvet Island</item>
<item>Brazil</item>
<item>British Indian Ocean Territory</item>
<item>British Virgin Islands</item>
<item>Brunei</item>
<item>Bulgaria</item>
<item>Burkina Faso</item>
<item>Burundi</item>
<item>Cambodia</item>
<item>Cameroon</item>
<item>Canada</item>
<item>Cape Verde</item>
<item>Cayman Islands</item>
<item>Central African Republic</item>
<item>Chad</item>
<item>Chile</item>
<item>China</item>
<item>Christmas Island</item>
<item>Cocos (Keeling) Islands</item>
<item>Colombia</item>
<item>Comoros</item>
<item>Congo</item>
<item>Cook Islands</item>
<item>Costa Rica</item>
<item>Cote d\'Ivoire</item>
<item>Croatia</item>
<item>Cuba</item>
<item>Cyprus</item>
<item>Czech Republic</item>
<item>Democratic Republic of the Congo</item>
<item>Denmark</item>
<item>Djibouti</item>
<item>Dominica</item>
<item>Dominican Republic</item>
<item>East Timor</item>
<item>Ecuador</item>
<item>Egypt</item>
<item>El Salvador</item>
<item>Equatorial Guinea</item>
<item>Eritrea</item>
<item>Estonia</item>
<item>Ethiopia</item>
<item>Faeroe Islands</item>
<item>Falkland Islands</item>
<item>Fiji</item>
<item>Finland</item>
<item>Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia</item>
<item>France</item>
<item>French Guiana</item>
<item>French Polynesia</item>
<item>French Southern Territories</item>
<item>Gabon</item>
<item>Georgia</item>
<item>Germany</item>
<item>Ghana</item>
<item>Gibraltar</item>
<item>Greece</item>
<item>Greenland</item>
<item>Grenada</item>
<item>Guadeloupe</item>
<item>Guam</item>
<item>Guatemala</item>
<item>Guinea</item>
<item>Guinea-Bissau</item>
<item>Guyana</item>
<item>Haiti</item>
<item>Heard Island and McDonald Islands</item>
<item>Honduras</item>
<item>Hong Kong</item>
<item>Hungary</item>
<item>Iceland</item>
<item>India</item>
<item>Indonesia</item>
<item>Iran</item>
<item>Iraq</item>
<item>Ireland</item>
<item>Israel</item>
<item>Italy</item>
<item>Jamaica</item>
<item>Japan</item>
<item>Jordan</item>
<item>Kazakhstan</item>
<item>Kenya</item>
<item>Kiribati</item>
<item>Kuwait</item>
<item>Kyrgyzstan</item>
<item>Laos</item>
<item>Latvia</item>
<item>Lebanon</item>
<item>Lesotho</item>
<item>Liberia</item>
<item>Libya</item>
<item>Liechtenstein</item>
<item>Lithuania</item>
<item>Luxembourg</item>
<item>Macau</item>
<item>Madagascar</item>
<item>Malawi</item>
<item>Malaysia</item>
<item>Maldives</item>
<item>Mali</item>
<item>Malta</item>
<item>Marshall Islands</item>
<item>Martinique</item>
<item>Mauritania</item>
<item>Mauritius</item>
<item>Mayotte</item>
<item>Mexico</item>
<item>Micronesia</item>
<item>Moldova</item>
<item>Monaco</item>
<item>Mongolia</item>
<item>Montserrat</item>
<item>Morocco</item>
<item>Mozambique</item>
<item>Myanmar</item>
<item>Namibia</item>
<item>Nauru</item>
<item>Nepal</item>
<item>Netherlands</item>
<item>Netherlands Antilles</item>
<item>New Caledonia</item>
<item>New Zealand</item>
<item>Nicaragua</item>
<item>Niger</item>
<item>Nigeria</item>
<item>Niue</item>
<item>Norfolk Island</item>
<item>North Korea</item>
<item>Northern Marianas</item>
<item>Norway</item>
<item>Oman</item>
<item>Pakistan</item>
<item>Palau</item>
<item>Panama</item>
<item>Papua New Guinea</item>
<item>Paraguay</item>
<item>Peru</item>
<item>Philippines</item>
<item>Pitcairn Islands</item>
<item>Poland</item>
<item>Portugal</item>
<item>Puerto Rico</item>
<item>Qatar</item>
<item>Reunion</item>
<item>Romania</item>
<item>Russia</item>
<item>Rwanda</item>
<item>Sqo Tome and Principe</item>
<item>Saint Helena</item>
<item>Saint Kitts and Nevis</item>
<item>Saint Lucia</item>
<item>Saint Pierre and Miquelon</item>
<item>Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</item>
<item>Samoa</item>
<item>San Marino</item>
<item>Saudi Arabia</item>
<item>Senegal</item>
<item>Seychelles</item>
<item>Sierra Leone</item>
<item>Singapore</item>
<item>Slovakia</item>
<item>Slovenia</item>
<item>Solomon Islands</item>
<item>Somalia</item>
<item>South Africa</item>
<item>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</item>
<item>South Korea</item>
<item>Spain</item>
<item>Sri Lanka</item>
<item>Sudan</item>
<item>Suriname</item>
<item>Svalbard and Jan Mayen</item>
<item>Swaziland</item>
<item>Sweden</item>
<item>Switzerland</item>
<item>Syria</item>
<item>Taiwan</item>
<item>Tajikistan</item>
<item>Tanzania</item>
<item>Thailand</item>
<item>The Bahamas</item>
<item>The Gambia</item>
<item>Togo</item>
<item>Tokelau</item>
<item>Tonga</item>
<item>Trinidad and Tobago</item>
<item>Tunisia</item>
<item>Turkey</item>
<item>Turkmenistan</item>
<item>Turks and Caicos Islands</item>
<item>Tuvalu</item>
<item>Virgin Islands</item>
<item>Uganda</item>
<item>Ukraine</item>
<item>United Arab Emirates</item>
<item>United Kingdom</item>
<item>United States</item>
<item>United States Minor Outlying Islands</item>
<item>Uruguay</item>
<item>Uzbekistan</item>
<item>Vanuatu</item>
<item>Vatican City</item>
<item>Venezuela</item>
<item>Vietnam</item>
<item>Wallis and Futuna</item>
<item>Western Sahara</item>
<item>Yemen</item>
<item>Yugoslavia</item>
<item>Zambia</item>
<item>Zimbabwe</item>

</string-array>



<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />
```

Comment: where did you put your country code?

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.ketan.ramani;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Ketan Ramani
 */

public class CountryCodeSpinner extends AppCompatSpinner {

    private ArrayList<CountryModel> arrayList;
    private CountryCodeAdapter countryCodeAdapter;

    public CountryCodeSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CountryCodeSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        fillCountryList();
        countryCodeAdapter = new CountryCodeAdapter(context, arrayList);
        //countryCodeAdapter = new CountryCodeAdapter(context, R.layout.spinner_country_code, arrayList);
        super.setAdapter(countryCodeAdapter);
    }

    public CountryCodeSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        fillCountryList();
        countryCodeAdapter = new CountryCodeAdapter(context, arrayList);
        //countryCodeAdapter = new CountryCodeAdapter(context, R.layout.spinner_country_code, arrayList);
        super.setAdapter(countryCodeAdapter);
    }

    private void fillCountryList() {
        //https://emojipedia.org/flags/
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.clear();
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("af", "Afghanistan", "+93", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("al", "Albania", "+355", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("dz", "Algeria", "+213", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("as", "American Samoa", "+1684", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ad", "Andorra", "+376", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ao", "Angola", "+244", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ai", "Anguilla", "+1264", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("aq", "Antarctica", "+672", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ag", "Antigua and Barbuda", "+1268", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ar", "Argentina", "+54", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("am", "Armenia", "+374", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("aw", "Aruba", "+297", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("au", "Australia", "+61", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("at", "Austria", "+43", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("az", "Azerbaijan", "+994", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bs", "Bahamas", "+1242", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bh", "Bahrain", "+973", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bd", "Bangladesh", "+880", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bb", "Barbados", "+1242", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("by", "Belarus", "+375", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("be", "Belgium", "+32", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bz", "Belize", "+501", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bj", "Benin", "+229", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bm", "Bermuda", "+1441", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bt", "Bhutan", "+975", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bo", "Bolivia", "+591", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ba", "Bosnia And Herzegovina", "+387", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bw", "Botswana", "+267", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("br", "Brazil", "+55", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("io", "British Indian Ocean Territory", "+246", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("vg", "British Virgin Islands", "+1284", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bn", "Brunei Darussalam", "+673", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bg", "Bulgaria", "+359", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bf", "Burkina Faso", "+226", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bi", "Burundi", "+257", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("kh", "Cambodia", "+855", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cm", "Cameroon", "+237", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ca", "Canada", "+1", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cv", "Cape Verde", "+238", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ky", "Cayman Islands", "+345", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cf", "Central African Republic", "+236", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("td", "Chad", "+235", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cl", "Chile", "+56", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cn", "China", "+86", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cx", "Christmas Island", "+61", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cc", "Cocos (keeling) Islands", "+61", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("co", "Colombia", "+57", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("km", "Comoros", "+269", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ck", "Cook Islands", "+682", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cr", "Costa Rica", "+506", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("hr", "Croatia", "+385", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cu", "Cuba", "+53", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cy", "Cyprus", "+357", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cz", "Czech Republic", "+420", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ci", "Côte D'ivoire", "+225", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cd", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "+243", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("dk", "Denmark", "+45", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("dj", "Djibouti", "+253", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("dm", "Dominica", "+1767", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("do", "Dominican Republic", "+1849", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ec", "Ecuador", "+593", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("eg", "Egypt", "+20", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sv", "El Salvador", "+503", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gq", "Equatorial Guinea", "+240", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("er", "Eritrea", "+291", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ee", "Estonia", "+372", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("et", "Ethiopia", "+251", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("fk", "Falkland Islands (malvinas)", "+500", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("fo", "Faroe Islands", "+298", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("fj", "Fiji", "+679", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("fi", "Finland", "+358", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("fr", "France", "+33", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gf", "French Guiana", "+594", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pf", "French Polynesia", "+689", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ga", "Gabon", "+241", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gm", "Gambia", "+220", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ge", "Georgia", "+995", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("de", "Germany", "+49", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gh", "Ghana", "+233", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gi", "Gibraltar", "+350", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gr", "Greece", "+30", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gl", "Greenland", "+299", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gd", "Grenada", "+1473", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gp", "Guadeloupe", "+590", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gu", "Guam", "+1671", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gt", "Guatemala", "+502", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gg", "Guernsey", "+44", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gn", "Guinea", "+224", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gw", "Guinea-Bissau", "+245", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gy", "Guyana", "+592", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ht", "Haiti", "+509", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("va", "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "+379", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("hn", "Honduras", "+504", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("hk", "Hong Kong", "+852", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("hu", "Hungary", "+36", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("is", "Iceland", "+354", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("in", "India", "+91", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("id", "Indonesia", "+62", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ir", "Iran", "+98", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("iq", "Iraq", "+964", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ie", "Ireland", "+353", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("im", "Isle Of Man", "+44", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("il", "Israel", "+972", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("it", "Italy", "+39", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("jm", "Jamaica", "+1876", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("jp", "Japan", "+81", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("je", "Jersey", "+44", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("jo", "Jordan", "+962", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("kz", "Kazakhstan", "+7", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ke", "Kenya", "+254", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ki", "Kiribati", "+686", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("xk", "Kosovo", "+383", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("kw", "Kuwait", "+965", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("kg", "Kyrgyzstan", "+996", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("la", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "+856", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("lv", "Latvia", "+371", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("lb", "Lebanon", "+961", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ls", "Lesotho", "+266", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("lr", "Liberia", "+231", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ly", "Libya", "+218", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("li", "Liechtenstein", "+423", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("lt", "Lithuania", "+370", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("lu", "Luxembourg", "+352", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mo", "Macao Sar China", "+853", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mk", "Macedonia", "+389", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mg", "Madagascar", "+261", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mw", "Malawi", "+265", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("my", "Malaysia", "+60", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mv", "Maldives", "+960", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ml", "Mali", "+223", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mt", "Malta", "+356", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mh", "Marshall Islands", "+692", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mq", "Martinique", "+596", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mr", "Mauritania", "+222", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mu", "Mauritius", "+230", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("yt", "Mayotte", "+262", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mx", "Mexico", "+52", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("fm", "Micronesia", "+691", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("md", "Moldova", "+373", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mc", "Monaco", "+377", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mn", "Mongolia", "+976", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("me", "Montenegro", "+382", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ms", "Montserrat", "+1664", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ma", "Morocco", "+212", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mz", "Mozambique", "+258", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mm", "Myanmar (Burma)", "+95", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("na", "Namibia", "+264", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("nr", "Nauru", "+674", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("np", "Nepal", "+977", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("nl", "Netherlands", "+31", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("nc", "New Caledonia", "+687", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("nz", "New Zealand", "+64", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ni", "Nicaragua", "+505", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ne", "Niger", "+227", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ng", "Nigeria", "+234", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("nu", "Niue", "+683", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("nf", "Norfolk Island", "+1670", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("kp", "North Korea", "+672", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mp", "Northern Mariana Islands", "+850", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("no", "Norway", "+47", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("om", "Oman", "+968", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pk", "Pakistan", "+92", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pw", "Palau", "+680", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ps", "Palestinian Territory, Occupied", "+970", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pa", "Panama", "+507", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pg", "Papua New Guinea", "+675", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("py", "Paraguay", "+595", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pe", "Peru", "+51", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ph", "Philippines", "+63", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pn", "Pitcairn Islands", "+870", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pl", "Poland", "+48", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pt", "Portugal", "+351", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pr", "Puerto Rico", "+1939", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("qa", "Qatar", "+974", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("cg", "Republic of the Congo - Brazzaville", "+242", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ro", "Romania", "+40", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ru", "Russian Federation", "+7", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("rw", "Rwanda", "+250", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("re", "Réunion", "+262", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("bl", "Saint Barthélemy", "+590", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sh", "Saint Helena", "+290", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("kn", "Saint Kitts & Nevis", "+1869", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("lc", "Saint Lucia", "+1758", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("mf", "Saint Martin", "+590", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("pm", "Saint Pierre & Miquelon", "+508", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("vc", "Saint Vincent & The Grenadines", "+1784", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ws", "Samoa", "+685", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sm", "San Marino", "+378", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("st", "Sao Tome & Principe", "+239", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sa", "Saudi Arabia", "+966", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sn", "Senegal", "+221", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("rs", "Serbia", "+381", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sc", "Seychelles", "+248", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sl", "Sierra Leone", "+232", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sg", "Singapore", "+65", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sx", "Sint Maarten", "+1", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sk", "Slovakia", "+421", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("si", "Slovenia", "+386", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sb", "Solomon Islands", "+677", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("so", "Somalia", "+252", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("za", "South Africa", "+27", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gs", "South Africa (South Georgia & South Sandwich Islands)", "+500", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("kr", "South Korea", "+82", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ss", "South Sudan", "+211", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("es", "Spain", "+34", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("lk", "Sri Lanka", "+94", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sd", "Sudan", "+249", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sr", "Suriname", "+597", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sz", "Swaziland", "+268", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("se", "Sweden", "+46", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ch", "Switzerland", "+41", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("sy", "Syrian Arab Republic", "+963", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tw", "Taiwan", "+886", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tj", "Tajikistan", "+992", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tz", "Tanzania", "+255", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("th", "Thailand", "+66", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tl", "Timor-Leste", "+670", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tg", "Togo", "+228", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tk", "Tokelau", "+690", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("to", "Tonga", "+676", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tt", "Trinidad & Tobago", "+1868", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tn", "Tunisia", "+216", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tr", "Turkey", "+90", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tm", "Turkmenistan", "+993", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tc", "Turks & Caicos Islands", "+1649", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("tv", "Tuvalu", "+688", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ug", "Uganda", "+256", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ua", "Ukraine", "+380", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ae", "United Arab Emirates", "+971", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("gb", "United Kingdom", "+44", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("us", "United States", "+1", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("uy", "Uruguay", "+598", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("vi", "US Virgin Islands", "+1340", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("uz", "Uzbekistan", "+998", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("vu", "Vanuatu", "+678", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ve", "Venezuela", "+58", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("vn", "Vietnam", "+84", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("wf", "Wallis And Futuna", "+681", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ye", "Yemen", "+967", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("zm", "Zambia", "+260", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("zw", "Zimbabwe", "+263", ""));
        arrayList.add(new CountryModel("ax", "Åland Islands", "+358", ""));
    }

    class CountryModel {

        private String iso, phoneCode, countryName, countryFlag;

        public CountryModel(String iso, String countryName, String phoneCode, String countryFlag) {
            this.iso = iso;
            this.countryName = countryName;
            this.phoneCode = phoneCode;
            this.countryFlag = countryFlag;
        }

        public String getIso() {
            return iso;
        }

        public void setIso(String iso) {
            this.iso = iso;
        }

        public String getPhoneCode() {
            return phoneCode;
        }

        public void setPhoneCode(String phoneCode) {
            this.phoneCode = phoneCode;
        }

        public String getCountryName() {
            return countryName;
        }

        public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
            this.countryName = countryName;
        }

        public String getCountryFlag() {
            return countryFlag;
        }

        public void setCountryFlag(String countryFlag) {
            this.countryFlag = countryFlag;
        }
    }

    public class CountryCodeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CountryModel> {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<CountryModel> arrayList;
        private int resource;

        public CountryCodeAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<CountryModel> arrayList) {
            super(context, 0, arrayList);
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
        }

        public CountryCodeAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, ArrayList<CountryModel> arrayList) {
            super(context, resource, 0, arrayList);
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
            this.resource = resource;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            return createItemView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public @NonNull
        View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            return createItemView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        private View createItemView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final View view;

            CountryModel model = arrayList.get(position);

            if (resource == 0) {
                LinearLayoutCompat rootLayout = new LinearLayoutCompat(context);
                rootLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                AppCompatTextView ccTextView = new AppCompatTextView(context);
                ccTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ccTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                ccTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                ccTextView.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
                ccTextView.setTextSize(15);
                ccTextView.setText(model.getCountryFlag() + "  " + model.getCountryName() + "  (" + model.getPhoneCode() + ")");
                rootLayout.addView(ccTextView);
                view = rootLayout;
            } else {
                view = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
                AppCompatTextView tvCountry = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
                tvCountry.setText(model.getCountryFlag() + "  " + model.getCountryName() + "  (" + model.getPhoneCode() + ")");
            }

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

**spinner_country_code.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        tools:text="Spinner Default Title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**USE OF CLASS IN XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.ketan.ramani.CountryCodeSpinner
        android:id="@+id/ccs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**USE OF CLASS IN JAVA**

```
private CountryCodeSpinner ccs;
ccs = findViewById(R.id.ccs);
ccs.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CountryCodeSpinner.CountryModel model = (CountryCodeSpinner.CountryModel) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        Log.e("KetanRamani", ": " + model.getPhoneCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

**GET COUNTRY CODE VALUE USING BELOW CODE**

```
CountryCodeSpinner.CountryModel model = (CountryCodeSpinner.CountryModel) ccs.getSelectedItem();
Log.e("KetanRamani", ": " + model.getPhoneCode() + " " + model.getCountryName());
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an array of array into your strings.xml

First declare an array for each country

```
<string-array name="data01">
    <item name="code">01</item>
    <item name="country">Albania</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="data02">
    <item name="code">02</item>
    <item name="country">Algeria</item>
</string-array>
<!--
...
-->
```

Then declare the array of array

```
<array name="countries">
    <item>@array/data01</item>
    <item>@array/data02</item>
    <!--     ...        -->
</array>
```

Once this done in your activity you just have to parse this array content and keep references on both countries and codes

```
Resources r = getResources();
TypedArray countrieCodes = r.obtainTypedArray(R.array.countries);

ArrayList<String> country = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> code = new ArrayList<String>();

int cpt = countrieCodes.length();
for (int i = 0; i < cpt; ++i) {
    int id = countrieCodes.getResourceId(i, 0);
    code.add(r.getStringArray(id)[0]);
    country.add(r.getStringArray(id)[1]);
}

countrieCodes.recycle(); 

final ArrayList<String> fCode = code;
final ArrayList<String> fCountry = country;

final Spinner p = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);
p.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
p.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        String selectedCountry = (String)p.getSelectedItem();
        int selectedPosition = fCountry.indexOf(selectedCountry);
        String correspondingCode = fCode.get(selectedPosition);
        // Here is your corresponding country code
        System.out.println(correspondingCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display the ISD CODE in each country? it can be done using IF statement or Switch. but sure it will take a lot of code. You can use an array or arrayList like this:

```
String[] ISD_CODE = {"+639","+123",......} //example only



   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long id) {
               final String result = ISD_CODE[position];
    }
```

Of course it must be the same position as in your array of countries but i suggest you must use a HashMap for that.

Answer (score 0):

[Country Code Picker (CCP)](https://goo.gl/1X7BaC) library might help you. It will save you from boilerplate code. You just need to place CountryCodePicker view in your layout xml.

This is CCP view [image].

[Download Sample application](https://goo.gl/8u8mJQ) from PlayStore.

Your view will look like with your phone editText. [image: CCP view]

Clicking on CCP will open a dialog with list of country to select from. Here you can search country with country name, code name, phone code.[image]
Selected country details can be read easily. For more details go to [Library's Github page](https://goo.gl/1X7BaC).

This library can give you full number by combining country code and carrier number, but it does not verify the structure of number.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code it may help you

```
Locale[] locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
    String country;
    for( Locale loc : locale ){
        country = loc.getDisplayCountry();
        if( country.length() > 0 && !countries.contains(country) ){
            countries.add( country );
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(countries, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    Spinner citizenship = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.input_citizenship);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);
    citizenship.setAdapter(adapter);##
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;



public class NextActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);
        String[] countery = {"Afghanistan","Albania"
                ,"Algeria"
                ,"Andorra"
                ,"Angola"
                ,"Anguilla"
                ,"Antigua & Barbuda"
                ,"Argentina"
                ,"Armenia"
                ,"Australia"
                ,"Austria"
                ,"Azerbaijan"
                ,"Bahamas"
                ,"Bahrain"
                ,"Bangladesh"
                ,"Barbados"
                ,"Belarus"
                ,"Belgium"
                ,"Belize"
                ,"Benin"
                ,"Bermuda"
                ,"Bhutan"
                ,"Bolivia"
                ,"Bosnia & Herzegovina"
                ,"Botswana"
                ,"Brazil"
                ,"Brunei Darussalam"
                ,"Bulgaria"
                ,"Burkina Faso"
                ,"Myanmar/Burma"
                ,"Burundi"
                ,"Cambodia"
                ,"Cameroon"
                ,"Canada"
                ,"Cape Verde"
                ,"Cayman Islands"
                ,"Central African Republic"
                ,"Chad"
                ,"Chile"
                ,"China"
                ,"Colombia"
                ,"Comoros"
                ,"Congo"
                ,"Costa Rica"
                ,"Croatia"
                ,"Cuba"
                ,"Cyprus"
                ,"Czech Republic"
                ,"Democratic Republic of the Congo"
                ,"Denmark"
                ,"Djibouti"
                ,"Dominican Republic"
                ,"Dominica"
                ,"Ecuador"
                ,"Egypt"
                ,"El Salvador"
                ,"Equatorial Guinea"
                ,"Eritrea"
                ,"Estonia"
                ,"Ethiopia"
                ,"Fiji"
                ,"Finland"
                ,"France"
                ,"French Guiana"
                ,"Gabon"
                ,"Gambia"
                ,"Georgia"
                ,"Germany"
                ,"Ghana"
                ,"Great Britain"
                ,"Greece"
                ,"Grenada"
                ,"Guadeloupe"
                ,"Guatemala"
                ,"Guinea"
                ,"Guinea-Bissau"
                ,"Guyana"
                ,"Haiti"
                ,"Honduras"
                ,"Hungary"
                ,"Iceland"
                ,"India"
                ,"Indonesia"
                ,"Iran"
                ,"Iraq"
                ,"Israel and the Occupied Territories"
                ,"Italy"
                ,"Ivory Coast (Cote d'Ivoire)"
                ,"Jamaica"
                ,"Japan"
                ,"Jordan"
                ,"Kazakhstan"
                ,"Kenya"
                ,"Kosovo"
                ,"Kuwait"
                ,"Kyrgyz Republic (Kyrgyzstan)"
                ,"Laos"
                ,"Latvia"
                ,"Lebanon"
                ,"Lesotho"
                ,"Liberia"
                ,"Libya"
                ,"Liechtenstein"
                ,"Lithuania"
                ,"Luxembourg"
                ,"Republic of Macedonia"
                ,"Madagascar"
                ,"Malawi"
                ,"Malaysia"
                ,"Maldives"
                ,"Mali"
                ,"Malta"
                ,"Martinique"
                ,"Mauritania"
                ,"Mauritius"
                ,"Mayotte"
                ,"Mexico"
                ,"Moldova, Republic of Monaco"
                ,"Mongolia"
                ,"Montenegro"
                ,"Montserrat"
                ,"Morocco"
                ,"Mozambique"
                ,"Namibia"
                ,"Nepal"
                ,"Netherlands"
                ,"New Zealand"
                ,"Nicaragua"
                ,"Niger"
                ,"Nigeria"
                ,"Korea, Democratic Republic of (North Korea)"
                ,"Norway"
                ,"Oman"
                ,"Pacific Islands"
                ,"Pakistan"
                ,"Panama"
                ,"Papua New Guinea"
                ,"Paraguay"
                ,"Peru"
                ,"Philippines"
                ,"Poland"
                ,"Portugal"
                ,"Puerto Rico"
                ,"Qatar"
                ,"Reunion"
                ,"Romania"
                ,"Russian Federation"
                ,"Rwanda"
                ,"Saint Kitts and Nevis"
                ,"Saint Lucia"
                ,"Saint Vincent's & Grenadines"
                ,"Samoa"
                ,"Sao Tome and Principe"
                ,"Saudi Arabia"
                ,"Senegal"
                ,"Serbia"
                ,"Seychelles"
                ,"Sierra Leone"
                ,"Singapore"
                ,"Slovak Republic "
                ,"Slovenia"
                ,"Solomon Islands"
                ,"Somalia"
                ,"South Africa"
                ,"Korea, Republic of (South Korea)"
                ,"South Sudan"
                ,"Spain"
                ,"Sri Lanka"
                ,"Sudan"
                ,"Suriname"
                ,"Swaziland"
                ,"Sweden"
                ,"Switzerland"
                ,"Syria"
                ,"Tajikistan"
                ,"Tanzania"
                ,"Thailand"
                ,"Timor Leste"
                ,"Togo"
                ,"Trinidad & Tobago"
                ,"Tunisia"
                ,"Turkey"
                ,"Turkmenistan"
                ,"Turks & Caicos Islands"
                ,"Uganda"
                ,"Ukraine"
                ,"United Arab Emirates"
                ,"United States of America (USA)"
                ,"Uruguay"
                ,"Uzbekistan"
                ,"Venezuela"
                ,"Vietnam"
                ,"Virgin Islands (UK)"
                ,"Virgin Islands (US)"
                ,"Yemen"
                ,"Zambia"
                ,"Zimbabwe"};
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(aa);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you add explaination for your code.